# Packer with vsphere waiting for IP timeout

Tags: vmware, packer, vsphere

I am attempting to create VMWare templates using Packer.  I have a simple file that is essentially a copy of https://github.com/guillermo-musumeci/packer-vsphere-iso-windows/tree/master/win2019.base.

When I build this it times out at "Waiting for IP".

The network it is using is set for static IP, so I suspect it is that, but how do I define a static IP for this? and does it really need this for template creation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I’ve had similar issues with vsphere-iso packer build. It was caused by using the wrong IP for the HTTP directory especially when I was on my company’s VPN vs being hardwired. Thus, it was continually stuck at 'Waiting for IP'. The issue was the order of priority that packer uses to determine what interface to use for the HTTP directory which contains my kickstarter file. The interface that it was choosing was not accessible from the vsphere instance. Could this be the issue?

How we solved this, is that we actually have a shell wrapper that calls packer. Within that script, we ask the user for an IP that the HTTP directory should be accessed at. I use `ifconfig` and look at the 10. IP in the list. The shell script passes on that environmental variable to my packer's build.json. Its not the cleanest solution, but Ive been using this fix for months.